# Select Sql to mention column as variable

Tags: mysql

I did the following to exclude fields (whose type is 'longblob)' from a table.

1. SELECT group_concat(COLUMN_NAME) into @column  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'document' AND DATA_TYPE NOT IN ('longblob');
2. select @column from document;

It returns @column value alone rather than displaying value of the field.

**Ex:** if `@column = "id, name"`, it returns `"id, name"`  alone. Rather than displaying values of id & name respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT group_concat(COLUMN_NAME) into @column 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'document' AND DATA_TYPE NOT IN ('longblob');

set @stmt := concat('select ', @column , ' from document');

select @stmt;

PREPARE stmt FROM  @stmt;

EXECUTE stmt ;
```